# Access violation with ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am trying to use a DLL within a python script for a GUI using Tkinter.

I get this error:
`write_flag=dfd.newp_usb_send_ascii(ctypes.c_long(deviceID),ctypes.c_char_p(cmd),ctypes.c_ulong(lengt))) OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000081`

This is the definition for the ctypes function driver_func.py:

```
newp_usb_send_ascii = cpplibrary.newp_usb_send_ascii
newp_usb_send_ascii.argtypes = (ctypes.c_long,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_ulong)
newp_usb_send_ascii.restype = ctypes.c_long
```

I then use the newp_usb_send_ascii within functions.py:

```
import driver_func as dfd
def write(deviceID, cmd, length):
    write_flag = dfd.newp_usb_send_ascii(ctypes.c_long(deviceID),ctypes.c_char_p(cmd),ctypes.c_ulong(length))
    if write_flag != 0:
        print(f"myterminal> Write to {deviceID} not successful.\n")
    else:
        print(f"myterminal> The command {cmd} has been written to the controller successfully.\n")
```

Lastly, I call write within my GUI:

```
def get_Text(self,event):
        write_cmd = self.entry_var.get()
        write_cmd = bytes(write_cmd,'utf-8')
        write_cmd += b'\0'
        f.write(1,write_cmd,len(write_cmd))
```

I always get this error, if I remove the encoding I will have an error that it is not a byte, once the string is converted as a byte string i get this memory error.

The definition of the function in the DLL is as such: `long EXPORT newp_usb_send_ascii (long DeviceID, char* Command, unsigned long Length);`

I don't know why I get this error, especially since I passed an empty byte array to another function without problem with the same type as c_char_p.

Thank you.

I tried to pass the string as a string, an address too, as a byte string but I always get this error.

Comment: Show some documentation (if any). It would also be useful to post the string being sent. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The *write* function can be much simplified, *e.g.*: `write_flag = dfd.newp_usb_send_ascii(deviceID, cmd, len(cmd))`. Are you sure you need a *NUL* byte at the end since you're also sending the length?

Comment: @CristiFati I do not have any documentation, because I am writing this entirely. For the DLL the only thing I have is the definition as stated above. For the NUL byte, I'm not sure, apparently it is required by the ctypes.ct_char_p type. And I have tried with and without, I still get the same error. Plus the length is for the DLL's function anyways and not for the ctypes. For the string being sent it is any of the commands that the manufacturer gave for the controller I'm trying to interface (e.g. *IDN?)

Comment: It's not required, Why don't you post the *C* function code (as on *Python* side things seem correct)?

Comment: I think I did up there: long EXPORT newp_usb_send_ascii (long DeviceID, char* Command, unsigned long Length);

Comment: My read method does the same actually, but the error is at address 0x00....80

Comment: Not the prototype, the code, to see how are you handling the pointer.

Comment: What does valid C code look like that works with the function?

Comment: Ah sorry that's within the DLL, I can't give you the detail of the function unfortunalty